# Convert for loop output tuple into dataframe python

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, tuples, knime

Hi everybody I am executing in Knime a python code found in this website [here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-grid-search-sarima-model-hyperparameters-for-time-series-forecasting-in-python/)! , using the Knime-Python extension, but I require to export the best 3 models configurations into a dataframe  which are generated with a for loop and is represented into a tuple.

The original last bit of the code is

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # load dataset
    series = read_csv('daily-total-female-births.csv', header=0, index_col=0)
    data = series.values
    print(data.shape)
    # data split
    n_test = 165
    # model configs
    cfg_list = sarima_configs()
    # grid search
    scores = grid_search(data, cfg_list, n_test)
    print('done')
    # list top 3 configs
    for cfg, error in scores[:3]:
        print(cfg, error)
```

and should return

```
done
[(0, 1, 2), (2, 0, 2, 0), 't'] 54.767582003072874
[(0, 1, 1), (2, 0, 2, 0), 'ct'] 58.69987083057107
[(1, 1, 2), (0, 0, 1, 0), 't'] 58.709089340600094
```

So I modified the code with 2 failed attempts as follows:

Attempt: 1

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # load dataset
    series = read_csv('C:\\Users\\Downloads\\shampoo.txt', header=0, index_col=0, date_parser=custom_parser)
    data = series.values
    print(data.shape)
    # data split
    n_test = 12
    # model configs
    cfg_list = sarima_configs()
    # grid search
    scores = grid_search(data, cfg_list, n_test)
    print('done')
    # list top 3 configs
    for cfg, error in scores[:3]:
        df=pd.DataFrame(cfg, error)
        output_table = df
```

Attempt: 2

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    # load dataset
    series = read_csv('C:\\Users\\Downloads\\shampoo.txt', header=0, index_col=0, date_parser=custom_parser)
    data = series.values
    print(data.shape)
    # data split
    n_test = 12
    # model configs
    cfg_list = sarima_configs()
    # grid search
    scores = grid_search(data, cfg_list, n_test)
    print('done')
    # list top 3 configs
    for cfg, error in scores[:3]:
        df.append({'cfg': cfg, 'error': error},ignore_index=True)
    output_table = df
```

The matter is that Knime requires to define an output table such a pandas dataframe to execute the node (the smallest procesing unit).

I expect define the output_table like the following image (https://ibb.co/xCGqVtx)

Thank you

Comment: Yes, KNIME requires `output_table` to be a Pandas DataFrame. So have you tried creating one? See [the docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/dsintro.html) if you need help.

Comment: Thank you @nekomatic I will have a look on that, but I think that the last three lines of code in both attempts to create a Pandas DataFrame. Please let me know if something is missing.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that your main code is structure like a command-line python script, i.e. it expects that `__name__ == '__main__'`. In practice,  it is not the case. You can try to add a `print(__name__)` statement outside of the `if` construction. For the `Python Script` node, i get `builtins`.

So removing or adjusting the if statement will fix the problem